# "Toast" se oculta de manera automatica bootstrap + vue

Tags: bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Resulta que tengo este codigo que copide del mismo documento de bootstrap+vue y tengo un problema que es que se oculta de manera automatica y solo se puede ver por unos segundos el contenido

```
<template>
 <div class="p-3 bg-secondary progress-bar-striped" style="min-height: 170px;">
 <b-button class="mb-2" variant="primary" @click="$bvToast.show('example-toast')">
   Show toast
 </b-button>
 <b-toast id="example-toast" title="BootstrapVue" data-delay="5000">
  Hello, world! This is a toast message.
 </b-toast>
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Es lo que hacen los **toast**, mostrarse un ratito solo. Si quieres dejarlo fijo fíjate como lo hacen en https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/toast, o bien usa **alerts**, o quizás, ese `data-delay` lo puedes ajustar o quitar a ver si así te funciona mejor.  En esa page lo ponen así:  `static no-auto-hide`

Comment: Pasa que solo se muestra por unos segundos, y luego se oculta a pesar de que le ponga "static", probaré con el "no-auto-hide"

Comment: Y quitale tambien el `data-delay="5000"`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ya pude solucionarlo, tube que importar
`import { ToastPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'`
`Vue.use(ToastPlugin)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template>
 <div>
  <b-button @click="makeToast()">Show Toast</b-button>
  <b-button @click="makeToast(true)">Show Toast (appended)</b-button>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  data() {
   return {
     toastCount: 0
   }
  },
  methods: {
    makeToast(append = false) {
     this.toastCount++
     this.$bvToast.toast(`This is toast number ${this.toastCount}`, {
       title: 'BootstrapVue Toast',
       autoHideDelay: 5000,
       appendToast: append
     })
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

[Puedes guiarte de este enlace](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/toast)
utiliza el `autoHideDelay:5000` para definir un tiempo determinado en milisegundos